# How do I get Citrix to authenticate to my new AD servers?

Tags: citrix

In an effort to upgrade my environment, I added 2 new AD servers.  When I shutdown my old AD servers, my Citrix environment (MetaFrame XPe for Windows version 1.0 SP1) stopped authenticating users.  I've turned on my old AD servers, but my Citrix environment still won't authenticate.

I've generated a local account on the Citrix servers and confirmed I can authenticate with with on my ICA Client, but it won't authenticate my domain credentials.  How do I view and change what server(s) my Citrix environment is using to authenticate myself and my users?

Answer (score 0):

Two major things to look at are DNS (this is always the first thing to look at) and in your case, OS version.

1. What DNS servers are the Citrix machines using? Are they the old DCs, or the new ones? If the old ones, are they still valid DNS servers for the domain?
2. That version of Metaframe is incredibly old. What version of Windows (and SP) is it running on? What version of Windows were the old DCs (that you turned off) and what version are the new ones?

I assume that your Citrix servers are in the domain of the DCs? Can you give us some more details about your environment? We need a little more to go on, here. This really doesn't have much to do with Citrix as such : it's using the native Windows authentication mechanism, which can be broken by DNS problems or by a serious versioning difference if it's not accounted for by loosening certain security restrictions in newer operating systems.

Comment: 1) The DNS servers are the AD servers.  The settings were updated in the TCP/IP settings.  The old servers were brought back up, but that hasn't resolved the issue.  2) Windows Server 2000 SP4. Old DCs were Windows Server 2003.  New are Windows Server 2012.

Comment: For answer 1), you didn't say if that's the *new* ones or the *old* ones. And please provide some basic DNS-based AD troubleshooting from the Citrix boxes - what happens when you NSlookup your AD domain name?

Comment: If I `echo %logonserver%` it shows I'm using my new DNS/AD server.  `nslookup` shows I'm using my new DNS/AD server. If I do a DNS query, it shows it's querying against the new DNS/AD server, but it lists the old DNS servers.  I removed the old DNS servers from the list from my new DNS server, but I still cannot authenticate to Citrix with domain credentials